# plotting an image from a predicted value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a predicted value 'p' and when I print 'p' the output is :

```
[[ 6.8175583]
[ 9.99688  ]
[12.834187 ]
...
[ 1.4792776]
[ 3.741147 ]
[ 8.88671  ]]
```

Is there a way I can plot this as an image?

when I use `plt.imshow(p)` it shows me a single line :

[image: single line]

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a NumPy array to PIL image using `Image.fromarray`:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 

#assuming p is your array 
#w, h are the width and height you want for your image
img = Image.fromarray(p.reshape(w,h), 'L')
img.save('my.png')
img.show()
```

`L` mode indicates the array values represent luminance. The result will be a gray-scale image.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The image is not like an input image, image is full of noise, is it how it should look like? is there any way I can fix that?

Comment: @AshishShakya that's your algorithm problem... this method just draw the image out from your array as you want....